# Perfect in-sample size for out-sampling volatility prediction (EGARCH(1,1)

Tags: volatility, market-data, garch, historical-data, forecasting

I have a few questions regarding in-sample size for volatility forecasting in EGARCH(1,1). I'm currently sitting with a dataset consisting of 1387 trading days of the S&P-500 index. I would like to forecast the volatility for a giving 3 month hedging period.
However, for now I've split the dataset into 20 non-overlapping portfolios of 3 months, then using an in-sample size of 126 days, to predict for each.
But I was wondering if there was a formal rule of this? And if you can refer me to a paper where this is described?

Comment: There does not exist a general rule for the amount of data you need, in order to procure stable estimates in the GARCH model, since it is dependent on the data itself. From this [paper](https://www.atlantis-press.com/article/139.pdf) they recommend using a minimum of 1000 samples for a GARCH fit. In my opinion, an in-sample size of 126 days is definitely in the low end.

Comment: @Pleb yeah that was generally my concern, I also read that paper. However, I went with the in-sample size as Hull's rule of thumb for calculating historical volatility is of 90-180 days, that is of course not the same as a good in-sample size for GARCH models.